# Proof by Contrapositive: How to deal with questions that contains divisibility?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I have learned proof by contrapositive before, but all of them had a clear opposite case such as not odd is even or not greater than $5$ is less than or equal to $5$, but I have no idea how to deal with problems that involves divisibility

"If $n^2 + n - 1$ is divisible by $3$ then $n$ is divisible by $3$"

The contrapositive that I see is "If $n$ is not divisible by $3$, then $n^2 + n - 1$ is not divisible by $3$" and that's where I stuck. I cannot think of a way to represent all the cases "not divisible by $3$", and I have tried to use the property that if a number is divisible by $3$, then the sum of all its digits is divisible by $3$ but it did not work. I would appreciate any advice, thank you

Comment: There are two cases.  $n$ is of the form $3k+1$ and $n$ is of the form $3k+2$.

Answer (score 2):

For these types of questions where there is divisibility by a small number involved it's best to try all the possible values of $n \mod 3$ and rule out each and every one. For example, if $n\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ we have $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ so $n^2+n-1\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. Do the same to rule out the case $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ and deduce that $n$ has to be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is *not* divisible by $\require{cancel}3$, then $n=3k\pm1$, for some $k\in\Bbb Z$ (for instance, $2=3\times1-1$, $4=3\times1+1$, $5=3\times2-1$, and so on…), and therefore\begin{align}n^2+n-1&=(3k\pm1)^2+3k\pm1-1\\&=9k^2\pm6k\cancel{+1}+3k\pm1\cancel{-1}\\&=3(3k^2\pm2k+k)\pm1,\end{align}which is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: For this student, I'd suggest you justify your implication prior to "and therefore".  Even if only intuitive using 2, 4, 5, e.g..

Comment: @amWhy Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Nice.  Even mentioning in any three consecutive numbers, one will be (3k-1), one 3k, and one (3k+1) for any integer k, ... could help.  But I like your brevity.